# VPNService doesn't work in all app android

Tags: android, block, vpn, packet

I implemented a vpnservice that block all packets,it works in most app and blocks fine but it doesn't work in some apps . why is that ?
myVpnService is like below.

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                builder = new Builder();



                mInterface = builder.setSession("ClashDisconnect")
                        .addAddress("192.168.0.1", 32)
                        .addDnsServer("8.8.8.4")
                        .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 1).establish();
                Log.d("after establish", "yes");


                DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();

                // Connect to the server, localhost is used for demonstration only.
                tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8081));
                //d. Protect this socket, so package send by it will not be feedback to the vpn service.
                protect(tunnel.socket());

                //e. Use a loop to pass packets.
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Catch any exception
                Log.d("Exception", "in Catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (mInterface != null) {
                        mInterface.close();
                        mInterface = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }

    }, "MyVpnRunnable");

    //start the service
    mThread.start();

            onDestroy();
        }
    };



    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mThread != null) {
        mThread.interrupt();
        mThread = null;
        builder = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and another weird problem is it work in some phone but not all phone .

Comment: Where did this code come from? Did you write it yourself based on some docs or is it based on an example/tutorial? It could help if you referenced your sources.

Comment: It's from this page : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/